# Triangle inequality for integrals proof

Tags: integration, inequality

I'm having a bit of trouble proving the following inequality, using a graphic proof.

$$
\left| \int_a^b f \right | \le \int_a^b |f|
$$ 
It's difficult for me to imagine these sorts of problems so I'm quite lost.
Thank you

Comment: You look for a geometric argument? I suggest that you take a function $f$ that changes sign in an interval, and sketch the graphs of $f$ and $|f|$. Then think of what the integral means...

Comment: For the sum of a finite number of terms one has something called the *triangle inequality*.  Are you familiar with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look at an example of  $$\left| \int_a^b f \right | \le \int_a^b |f|$$

For $f(x) =x$  on the interval $[ -1,1]$ what is $  \int_a^b f $ ?

The answer is $\int _{-1}^{1} xdx = x^2/2|_{-1}^{1} =0$.

What about the $|x|$ on the same interval. Now your function looks like a $V$ and it is defined as $f(x) = x$ for $x\ge 0$ and    $f(x) = -x$ for $x\le 0$

Now you take the integral and you come up with   $$\int _{-1}^{1}| x|dx$$ = $$\int _{-1}^{0}(- x)dx +  \int _{0}^{1}( x)dx = 1$$

Clearly $0 \le 1$.

The important point is for  f(x) you may have negative values but for $|f(x)|$ we only have non-negative values.